# Function Display article

Tags: php, html

I am new in Wordpress ... I developed a theme and I want to display the contents of a specific item ID in a div.

For example...I create this div.

```
<div id="myarticle">

//function php WORDPRESS

</div>
```

What is the php function that helps me to display the content of an article?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

If you only want `The Content` (of the main editor of the post) displayed, you can use `echo get_the_content(the_ID)`. If you want more:

1. First, you have to **get the post data from the database**, with the function `get_post`, or doing a query with `WP_query`.
2. Then you can **output different parts like title, date, content**... accessing your variable properties, or doing a [Loop](http://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop), depending on what method you use.

I recommend you to examine other themes code to understand how it works, and of course [The Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/), that is the WordPress documentation. The basics are very easy.